# How can I define seed-nodes in runtime

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I have a akka cluster with application.conf like below:

```
 remote { // Remote configuration for this seed node
  enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
  netty.tcp {
    hostname = ""
    port = 2555
  }
}
cluster {
  seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://automation-akka-http@10.0.0.4:2555",
    "akka.tcp://automation-akka-http@10.0.0.5:2555"
  ] // Seed nodes of the cluster
  auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
}
```

Right now, the seed-nodes are hard-code. I want to configure a parameter here like this:

```
cluster {
  seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://automation-akka-http@${?HOST1}:2555",
    "akka.tcp://automation-akka-http@${?HOST2}:2555"
  ] // Seed nodes of the cluster
  auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
}
```

I know that I can define these parameters in sbt command for compile. But that will not resolve my problem, because I can only have seed nodes' IP in deployment phase. Is there a way to define these parameters on start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Akka Cluster Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#joining-to-seed-nodes)

You can join seed nodes programmatically with `Cluster(system).joinSeedNodes`.

According to [Akka API docs](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/cluster/Cluster.html#joinSeedNodes-scala.collection.immutable.Seq-) it takes a Sequence of `akka.actor.Address`, which would then be your seed node addresses.

So something like this should work:

```
val seeds = Seq(Address("akka.tcp", "RemoteSystem1", "host1", 1234),
                Address("akka.tcp", "RemoteSystem2", "host2", 1234)

Cluster(system).joinSeedNodes(seeds)
```

Where according to [Address API docs](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/Address.html#Address-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-)

- "akka.tcp" = protocol
- "RemoteSystem1" = Name of remote actor system
- "host1" = Host of remote actor system
- 1234 = Port of remote actor system

EDIT

Created a minimal example on [GitHub](https://github.com/thwiegan/so_ActorClusterExample)

```
val cluster = Cluster(context.system)

// Join the seed node with the given address
seedPort match {
  case Some(port) =>
    cluster.joinSeedNodes(immutable.Seq(Address("akka.tcp", "ClusterSystem", "127.0.0.1", port)))
  case _ =>
}
```

Can be run with sbt "run akkaPort [clusterPort]". So to initially start the cluster run with two identical ports:

```
sbt "run 1337 1337"
```

and then run an additional node with a different akkaPort:

```
sbt "run 1338 1337"
```

This node will then join.

If you omit the clusterPort parameter, it will not execute this line:

```
cluster.joinSeedNodes(immutable.Seq(Address("akka.tcp", "ClusterSystem", "127.0.0.1", port)))
```

And therefore just using the seed node from the application.conf file.

Comment: 1. Where shall I put these code? 2. If I use this code, how about the configuration in application.conf? Do they have conflict?

Comment: This code would go wherever you initialize your cluster, so probably at application startup. As for the config, that's a good point. I'll try to get a minimal example on github today.

Comment: @NewtonZou Updated my answer with a running example